# Text to Speech repeating weird text in german language

Tags: ios, swift, text-to-speech

I am using AVSpeechSynthesizer for TTS but it will repeat weird text like „homograf“ and „encore“. on the sentence here is the text I want to convert to speech "ActualValue 3261,Day 30,Month July,Year 1990,Age 32,Star Sign Leo,Birthday 30 July 1990,Days since birth 11974,Days until birthday 79,Born on which day Monday,Birthday this year Sunday"

Here is the Code I am using for Text to speech

```
var synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
synth.delegate = self
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

func playAudio(word: String){
    let myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: word)
    myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "de-DE")
    if myUtterance.voice != nil {
        myUtterance.rate = Float(ttsConfig.speed)/10.0
        myUtterance.preUtteranceDelay = 0.5
        if isPauseAudio {
            synth.pauseSpeaking(at: .immediate)
        } else {
            synth.continueSpeaking()
            print("SPEAK EVENT----> \(word)")
            synth.speak(myUtterance)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

same problem here with german settings.

```
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Es ist das Jahr 2023")
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "de-DE")
```

The Demo-String will be pronounced as: "Es ist das Jahr homograph 2023 homograph end"

This is happen on real devices only. In the Simulator the pronunciation is correct

Comment: I fixed this issues by replacing the numbers with the text. I only had one fixed number so this was easy for me. So instead of "In 5 Sekunden geht's los" I am using  "In fünf Sekunden geht's los".